Unable to create root@localhost mysql 5.7 or 8.0.31
I have received a mysql environment to work on and currently Audits are being performed.
What I see in mysql.user is 'root'@'%' created everywhere and it is required that access to root is to be restricted to 'root'@'localhost'.
As per this Adding a user to MySQL with 'name'@'%' fails with ERROR 1396 I suppose the root user was created without a hostname.
MySQL Version - is 8.0.31 and at some servers it is 5.7.44.
OS - CentOS
I tried creating the same 'root'@'localhost' and
I receive error on 8.0.31,
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

and a warning on 5.7.44.
Note    | 3163 | Authorization ID 'root'@'localhost' already exists.

And yes when I use \s, I see root@localhost connected.
and the user does not exist in mysql.user table at this point.
So when I try to do this,
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;

I receive
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

and it also breaks one out of two replicas with
Error 'You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root_new'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION'
The servers are started with --skip-name-resolve option in the config file and mysqld --print-defaults confirms the same.
So, I rather created root_new@localhost and granted all privileges with grant option, I receive another warning
MySQL is started in --skip-name-resolve mode; you must restart it without this switch for this grant to work

and at this point also the new user root_new@localhost does not exist in the mysql.user table on 5.7 or 8 too.
My question is, is it safe to restart the system with --skip-name-resolve disabled and then drop the 'root'@'%'?
I am able to log in with the new root_new user and then I dropped certain unwanted users also. When I use \s, it shows me root_new@localhost.
And what is the issue here? Does it have anything to do with enabling name resolution.

is it safe to restart the system with --skip-name-resolve disabled and then drop the 'root'@'%'? Ensure that there exists at least one another user which have COMPLETE privileges list with grant option, and that you can authenticate using this user account.

root@localhost is the default username for MySQL. The error you are receiving informs you that you are trying to create an already-existing user. Since you have an admin user that allows you to login to the database is resetting the password for root@localhost safe? (is there any application using this username?) if its safe then reset the password and remove the unwanted user after verifying that root@% is not used anywhere.
To reset root password you can follow the instruction inside this KB

yes but then it throws the --skip-name-resolve related warning when I created root_new@localhost. Warning - MySQL is started in --skip-name-resolve mode; you must restart it without this switch for this grant to work. Also root_new@localhost does not exist in the mysql.user table. I am able to log in to the server using root_new@localhost but it does not exist in the mysql.user, hence unsure about dropping the root@% user.
